# How to use custom ng-pattern function on form

Tags: angularjs

I have a form where I want to validate that the number entered is a correct Swedish SSN(social security number). On the html side I have the following:

```
<div layout="row" flex="100" layout-align="space-around start" layout-wrap>
    <md-input-container ng-if="uf.user.ssnType === 'svenskt'" md-no-float flex="45" flex-xs="100">
        <p>Personummer</p>

        <input type="text" flex-xs="100" md-min-length="13" ng-pattern="isValidSwedishSSN" placeholder="ÅÅÅÅMMDD-XXXX" ng-change="uf.searchUser()" required ng-model="uf.user.user.ssn"
            name="ssn" id="ssn" md-colors="{'backgroundColor': (form1.ssn.$invalid && uf.userClicked) ? 'primary-100' : 'primary-50', 'borderColor': (form1.ssn.$invalid && uf.userClicked) ? 'primary' : 'grey-300'}" tabindex="1">

        <div ng-if="uf.userClicked" ng-messages="(form1.ssn.$error)" role="alert">
            <div md-colors="{ 'color': 'primary' }" ng-message-exp="['required']">Måste fyllas i. </div>
        </div>

        <div ng-messages="(form1.ssn.$error)" role="alert">
            <div md-colors="{ 'color': 'primary' }" ng-message-exp="['pattern']"> Du måste skriva personnummer i formatet 'ÅÅÅÅMMDD-XXXX'.</div>
        </div>
```

in the .js I have tried the following to validate the ssn:

Validate Swedish Social Security Number (personnummer) using checksum

Note: this is somewhat simplified because it does not take into account
that the date of the number is valid (e.g. "000000-0000" does return as true)

```
$scope.isValidSwedishSSN = (function() {
var ssn = user.user.ssn;
ssn = ssn
    .replace(/\D/g, "")     // strip out all but digits
    .split("")              // convert string to array
    .reverse()              // reverse order for Luhn
    .slice(0, 10);          // keep only 10 digits (i.e. 1977 becomes 77)

// verify we got 10 digits, otherwise it is invalid
if (ssn.length != 10) {
    return false;
}

var sum = ssn
    // convert to number
    .map(function(n) {
        return Number(n);
    })
    // perform arithmetic and return sum
    .reduce(function(previous, current, index) {
        // multiply every other number with two
        if (index % 2) current *= 2;
        // if larger than 10 get sum of individual digits (also n-9)
        if (current > 9) current -= 9;
        // sum it up
        return previous + current;
    });

// sum must be divisible by 10
return 0 === sum % 10;
})();
```

At the moment I have two problems:

1. How do I get the form to check my custom isValidSwedishSSN when people type in the ssn?
2. I dont think I get the value in the field that the user have typed in the correct way

Comment: you can convert validateSsn to a separate directive itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `ng-model-options="{ allowInvalid: true }"` attribute to your input field. This will help you get the value typed in the field. You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-model-options.asp).

As for your first problem, get your isValidSwedishSSN to return true in case of valid input and false in case of invalid input. This value will be set in `ng-pattern`. Then in the form's `ng-submit`, check if the form is valid and then submit.

```
<form name='testFrom' ng-submit='testForm.$valid && submitFunc()'>
    <!-- form input fields -->
</form>
```

The form will not be submitted in case ng-pattern is false.